# How to test within a precision using Cgreen?

Tags: c, unit-testing, cunit

I need to test doubles in a unit test written using Cgreen. My comparison and generated values are very close, but `assert_double_equal` says

```
1.95 != 1.94887879
```

How can I tell Cgreen to test within a certain precision? This is close enough for me.

PS: Stackoverflow won't let me create a new tag for Cgreen, but I'm hoping some CUnit users have some experience using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`significant_figures_for_assert_double_are(int figures)`

From:

http://cgreen.sourceforge.net/index.php/documentation/building-test-suites-with-cgreen